# Is there such thing as an adjacent selector in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use the proper selectors for this code, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<ul id="message-list">
    <li class="clearfix message success unread">
        <a href="/messages/mark_read/61/" class="message-close"></a>
        <h4>
            <strong>
                Getting Real: The Smarter, Faster, Easier Way To Build A Successful Web Application
            </strong>
            has been added to your profile.
        </h4>
        <form action="/profile/tweet/NIZNQwAACAAJ/" method="post">
            <div style="display:none">
                <input type="hidden" value="3b723be17da67c5bc54b27a98a660d53" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="button tweet-button" value="Tweet This Book">
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
$('.tweet-button').click(function (e) {
    var $list_item = $(this).parent('ul li.message'); < ----- ? ? ?
    var $anchor = $(this).parent('a'); // ?? <------
});
```

I am trying to get the selector for the uppermost list item with class 'message' and the anchor tag adjacent to the form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Since `li.message` isn't an immediate ancestor of your button, use [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents) to search up the DOM tree until you reach `li.message`:

```
var $list_item = $(this).parents('li.message');
```

And since the anchor is a *sibling of the `form` parent* of your input, use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) *after* selecting the `.parent()` to get the anchor:

```
var $anchor = $(this).parent().siblings('a');
```

By the way,

- The `a` isn't adjacent to the `form`, although it is one of its sibling elements.
- Nesting an `input` directly in a `form` isn't valid HTML. jQuery will still work with it, but the validator will complain (if you care about that sort of thing).

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and traversing to the anchor using [`.prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev):

```
var $list_item = $(this).closest('li.message');
var $anchor = $(this).closest('form').prev().prev('.message-close');
```